# Asking how can I hide table?

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, hide

I have standings script, I used for soccer. 
As we know in soccer there are:

- Group’s games depend in points

And

- Head to head match which point table not important

My script deal with both kinds of games in same way. 
I mean the point table appears in both types. 
My question:

I want let points table visible in games depend in point and hide the table in head to head games.
I have (conference, season, and division id) for each game.
Is there any way to hide point table in head to head games according to (conference, season, and division id)?
Notes: the table that I want to work in it is “ standingstable “

I will put standings.php and if you need setting.php file i can add it later

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Current Standings</title>
<style type="text/css">
body, td {
 font: 13px "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Tahoma, Verdana;
}
a, a:visited {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #69c;
 color: #00019b;
 text-decoration: none;
}
th {
 text-align: left;
}

.standingstable {
width: 760px;
}

.gamestable, .scorestable, .teamhistory {
border-collapse: collapse;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
width: 700px;
}

.gamestable td, .gamestable th, .scorestable td, .scorestable th, .teamhistory td, .teamhistory th {
padding: 5px;
border: 1px solid black;
}

.gamestable tr, .scorestable tr, .teamhistory tr {
vertical-align: top;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<h2>Current Standings</h2>
<?php
require "settings.php";

if (isset($_GET['conf'])) {
    $confid = intval($_GET['conf']);
}
else {
    $confid = 0;
}
if (isset($_GET['team'])) {
    $team = intval($_GET['team']);
}
else {
    $team = 0;
}
if (isset($_GET['history'])) {
    $history = intval($_GET['history']);
}
else {
    $history = 0;
}

mysql_connect($sportsdb_host,$sportsdb_user,$sportsdb_pass);
@mysql_select_db($sportsdb_db) or die( "Unable to select database");

include 'standings_functions.php';

if ($history > 0) {
    // We need the team ID and the conference ID too
    if ($confid < 1 || $team < 1) {
        die ('Not enough information supplied');
    }
    print '<p><a href="?conf=' . $confid . '">Back to the conference standings</a></p>' . "\n";
    print '<p><a href="?conf=' . $confid . '&team=' . $team . '">Back to the team schedule</a></p>' . "\n";
    
    $query = 'SELECT teamname, masterteam FROM sportsdb_teams WHERE teamid = ' . $team . ' LIMIT 1';
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        die('No such team exists');
    }
    else {
        $teamname = mysql_result($result,0,"teamname");
        $masterteam = mysql_result($result,0,"masterteam");
    }
    print '<h3>' . $teamname . ' history</h3>' . "\n";
    $query = 'SELECT sportsdb_teams.teamid, sportsdb_teams.teamname, sportsdb_teams.teamwins, sportsdb_teams.teamlosses, sportsdb_teams.teamties, sportsdb_teams.teamforfeits, 
    sportsdb_divs.divname, 
    sportsdb_conferences.confname, sportsdb_conferences.confid,  
    sportsdb_seasons.seasonname 
    FROM sportsdb_teams, sportsdb_divs, sportsdb_conferences, sportsdb_seasons 
    WHERE sportsdb_teams.masterteam = ' . $masterteam . ' 
    AND sportsdb_teams.teamdiv = sportsdb_divs.divid 
    AND sportsdb_divs.conference = sportsdb_conferences.confid 
    AND sportsdb_conferences.season = sportsdb_seasons.seasonid 
    ORDER BY sportsdb_seasons.seasonorder';
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die ('Error in query: ' . $query);
?>
<table class="teamhistory">
    <tr>
        <th>Season</th>
        <th>Team</th>
        <th>Conference</th>
        <th>Division</th>
        <th>Wins</th>
        <th>Losses</th>
        <?php if ($show_ties) { ?><th>Ties</th><?php } ?>
        <?php if ($forfeits) { ?><th>Forfeits</th><?php } ?>
    </tr>
<?php
    while ($teams = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC) ) {
        $seasonname = htmlspecialchars($teams['seasonname'], ENT_QUOTES);
        print "\t" . '<tr>' . "\n";
        print "\t\t" . '<td>' . $seasonname . '</td>' . "\n";
        print "\t\t" . '<td><a href="?team=' . $teams['teamid'] . '&conf=' . $teams['confid'] . '">' . $teams['teamname'] . '</td>' . "\n";
        print "\t\t" . '<td><a href="?conf=' . $teams['confid'] . '">' . $teams['confname'] . '</a></td>' . "\n";
        print "\t\t" . '<td>' . $teams['divname'] . '</td>' . "\n";
        print "\t\t" . '<td>' . $teams['teamwins'] . '</td>' . "\n";
        print "\t\t" . '<td>' . $teams['teamlosses'] . '</td>' . "\n";
        if ($show_ties) {
            print "\t\t" . '<td>' . $teams['teamties'] . '</td>' . "\n";
        }
        if ($forfeits) {
            print "\t\t" . '<td>' . $teams['teamforfeits'] . '</td>' . "\n";
        }
        print "\t" . '</tr>' . "\n";
    }
    print '</table>' . "\n";
}
elseif ($team > 0) {
    // We need the conference ID too
    if ($confid < 1) {
        die ('Not enough information supplied');
    }
    
    print '<p><a href="?conf=' . $confid . '">Back to the conference standings</a></p>' . "\n";
    print '<h3>' . get_team_name($team). ': full schedule and scores</h3>' . "\n";
    print '<p><a href="?history=1&team=' . $team . '&conf=' . $confid . '">Team history</a></p>' . "\n";
    sls_team_schedule($team);
}

elseif ($confid > 0) {

// Allow sorting to occur
if (isset($_GET['sort'])) {
    $standings_sort = intval($_GET['sort']);
}
else {
    $standings_sort = 0;
}
switch ($standings_sort) {
/*
Available sort fields:

Name: teamname
Wins: teamwins
Losses: teamlosses
Ties: teamties
Forfeits: teamforfeits
Runs for: teamrf
Runs against: teamra
Games behind: gamesbehind
Points: points
Winning percentage: winningpct
Custom tie break: teamorder

Separate the fields by commas and always specify a sort order as DESC for descending and ASC for ascending
*/
case 1: // Sort by team name
$sort_order = "teamname ASC"; break;
case 2: // Sort by wins
$sort_order = "teamwins DESC, teamties DESC, teamlosses ASC, teamorder DESC"; break;
case 3: // Sort by losses
$sort_order = "teamlosses DESC, teamwins ASC, teamties ASC, teamorder DESC"; break;
case 4: // Sort by ties
$sort_order = "teamties DESC, teamwins DESC, teamlosses ASC, teamorder DESC"; break;
case 5: // Sort by forfeits
$sort_order = "teamforfeits DESC, teamwins ASC, teamties ASC, teamorder DESC"; break;
case 6: // Sort by games played
$sort_order = "gamesplayed DESC, teamwins DESC, teamties DESC, teamlosses ASC, teamorder DESC"; break;
case 7: // Sort by runs for
$sort_order = "teamrf DESC, teamwins ASC, teamties DESC, teamlosses ASC, teamorder DESC"; break;
case 8: // Sort by runs against
$sort_order = "teamra DESC, teamwins DESC, teamties ASC, teamlosses DESC, teamorder DESC"; break;
case 9: // Sort by games behind
$sort_order = "gamesbehind ASC, teamties DESC, teamwins DESC, teamlosses ASC, teamorder DESC"; break;
case 10: // Sort by points
$sort_order = "points DESC, teamwins DESC, winningpct DESC, teamorder DESC"; break;
default: // Sort by winning percentage
$standings_sort = 0; $sort_order = "winningpct DESC, teamorder DESC";
}
$division_sort = "";

// Different winning percentage calculations
switch ($winning_pct_calc) {
    case 2: // Treating a tie as a half win
    $winning_pct_formula = '((teamwins + (teamties / 2)) / (teamwins + teamties + teamlosses + teamforfeits))';
    break;

    case 3: // Treating winning percentage as number of points relative to total possible points
    $winning_pct_formula = '((teamwins * ' . $points_win . ' + teamforfeits * ' . $points_forfeit . ' + teamties * ' . $points_tie . ') / ((teamwins + teamties + teamlosses + teamforfeits) * ' . $points_win . '))';
    break;
    
    default: // Ignoring ties
    $winning_pct_formula = '(teamwins / (teamwins + teamlosses + teamforfeits))';
}

// print the conference name
$resultconf = mysql_query("SELECT sportsdb_conferences.confname, sportsdb_seasons.seasonid, sportsdb_seasons.seasonname FROM sportsdb_conferences, sportsdb_seasons WHERE sportsdb_conferences.confid = $confid AND sportsdb_conferences.season = sportsdb_seasons.seasonid LIMIT 1");
$confname = @mysql_result($resultconf, 0, 'confname') or die ('No such conference');
$seasonid = mysql_result($resultconf, 0, 'seasonid');
$seasonname = mysql_result($resultconf, 0, 'seasonname');
$seasonname = htmlspecialchars($seasonname, ENT_QUOTES);

print '<h2>' . $confname . ' (' . $seasonname . ')</h2>' . "\n";
print '<p><a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?season=' . $seasonid . '">Back to conference list</a></p>';
print "\n" . '<hr />' . "\n";

// Get the divisions

$resultconf = mysql_query("SELECT divname, divid FROM sportsdb_divs WHERE conference = $confid ORDER BY divorder");
$numconf = mysql_num_rows($resultconf);
if ($numconf == 0) {
print "<p>No divisions in this conference</p>\n";
}

else {
while ($divs = mysql_fetch_array($resultconf, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

// Loop through each division

$divname = $divs['divname'];
?>

<h3><?php print $divname; ?></h3>
<table class="standingstable">
    <tr>
        <td width="25%"><?php if ($standings_sort != 1) print '<a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?conf=$confid&sort=1\">"; ?><strong>Team Name</strong><?php if ($standings_sort != 1) print '</a>'; ?></td>
        <td><?php if ($standings_sort != 6) print '<a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?conf=$confid&sort=6\">"; ?><strong>GP</strong><?php if ($standings_sort != 2) print '</a>'; ?></td>
        <td><?php if ($standings_sort != 2) print '<a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?conf=$confid&sort=2\">"; ?><strong>Wins</strong><?php if ($standings_sort != 2) print '</a>'; ?></td>
        <td><?php if ($standings_sort != 3) print '<a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?conf=$confid&sort=3\">"; ?><strong>Losses</strong><?php if ($standings_sort != 3) print '</a>'; ?></td>
<?php if ($show_ties) { ?>
        <td><?php if ($standings_sort != 4) print '<a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?conf=$confid&sort=4\">"; ?><strong>Ties</strong><?php if ($standings_sort != 4) print '</a>'; ?></td>
<?php } ?>
<?php if ($forfeit) { ?>
        <td><?php if ($standings_sort != 5) print '<a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?conf=$confid&sort=5\">"; ?><strong>Forfeits</strong><?php if ($standings_sort != 5) print '</a>'; ?></td>
<?php } ?>
<?php if ($show_rfra) { ?>
        <td><?php if ($standings_sort != 7) print '<a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?conf=$confid&sort=7\">"; ?><strong>RF</strong><?php if ($standings_sort != 7) print '</a>'; ?></td>
        <td><?php if ($standings_sort != 8) print '<a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?conf=$confid&sort=8\">"; ?><strong>RA</strong><?php if ($standings_sort != 8) print '</a>'; ?></td>
<?php } ?>
<?php if ($show_gb) { ?>
        <td><?php if ($standings_sort != 9) print '<a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?conf=$confid&sort=9\">"; ?><strong>GB</strong><?php if ($standings_sort != 9) print '</a>'; ?></td>
<?php } ?>
        <td><?php if ($standings_sort != 0) print '<a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?conf=$confid&sort=0\">"; ?><strong>PCT</strong><?php if ($standings_sort != 0) print '</a>'; ?></td>
<?php if ($show_points) { ?>
        <td><?php if ($standings_sort != 10) print '<a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?conf=$confid&sort=10\">"; ?><strong>Points</strong><?php if ($standings_sort != 10) print '</a>'; ?></td>
<?php } ?>
    </tr>

<?php
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sportsdb_teams WHERE teamdiv = {$divs['divid']}";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$result_exist = mysql_result($result,0);

if ($result_exist) {
    $query = "SELECT teamid, teamname, teamwins, teamties, teamlosses, teamforfeits, teamrf, teamra, 
    (teamwins + teamties + teamlosses + teamforfeits) AS gamesplayed, 
    (teamwins * $points_win + teamforfeits * $points_forfeit + teamties * $points_tie) AS points, 
    $winning_pct_formula AS winningpct, 
    (teamwins - teamlosses - teamforfeits) AS leadervalue 
    FROM sportsdb_teams 
    WHERE teamdiv = {$divs['divid']} 
    ORDER BY leadervalue DESC, teamties DESC LIMIT 1";
    
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query");
    $results = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
    $winningpct = number_format($results['winningpct'], 3);
}

// Show the leader at the top for default sorting (games behind)

if ($standings_sort == 9) {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="?conf=<?php print $confid; ?>&team=<?php print $results['teamid']; ?>" title="View scores for <?php print $results['teamname']; ?>"><em><?php print $results['teamname']; ?></em></a></td>
        <td><?php print $results['gamesplayed']; ?></td>
        <td><?php print $results['teamwins']; ?></td>
        <td><?php print $results['teamlosses']; ?></td>
<?php if ($show_ties) { ?>
        <td><?php print $results['teamties']; ?></td>
<?php }
if ($forfeit) { ?>
        <td><?php print $results['teamforfeits']; ?></td>
<?php }
if ($show_rfra) { ?>
        <td><?php print $results['teamrf'];?></td>
        <td><?php print $results['teamra'];?></td>
<?php }
if ($show_gb) { ?>
        <td>---</td>
<?php } ?>
        <td><?php print $winningpct; ?></td>
<?php if ($show_points) { ?>
        <td><?php print $results['points'] ?></td>
<?php } ?>
    </tr>
<?php }

if ($result_exist) {
        $query="SELECT teamid, teamname, teamwins, teamties, teamlosses, teamforfeits, teamrf, teamra, 
        (teamwins + teamties + teamlosses + teamforfeits) AS gamesplayed, 
        (teamwins * $points_win + teamforfeits * $points_forfeit + teamties * $points_tie) AS points, 
        $winning_pct_formula AS winningpct, 
        ((({$results['leadervalue']}) - (teamwins - teamlosses - teamforfeits)) / 2) AS gamesbehind 
        FROM sportsdb_teams 
        WHERE teamdiv = {$divs['divid']}";

        if ($standings_sort == 9) {
            $query .= " AND teamid != {$results['teamid']}";
        }
        $query .= " AND active = 1" . $division_sort . " ORDER BY $sort_order";

        $result=mysql_query($query);
        $num=mysql_num_rows($result);

        while ($results = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $winningpct=number_format($results['winningpct'], 3);
            $gamesbehind = number_format($results['gamesbehind'],1);

            if ($gamesbehind == "0.0") {
                $gamesbehind = "---";
            }
?>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="?conf=<?php print $confid; ?>&team=<?php print $results['teamid']; ?>" title="View scores for <?php print $results['teamname']; ?>"><em><?php print $results['teamname']; ?></em></a></td>
        <td><?php print $results['gamesplayed']; ?></td>
        <td><?php print $results['teamwins']; ?></td>
        <td><?php print $results['teamlosses']; ?></td>
<?php if ($show_ties) { ?>
        <td><?php print $results['teamties']; ?></td>
<?php }
if ($forfeit) { ?>
        <td><?php print $results['teamforfeits']; ?></td>
<?php }
if ($show_rfra) { ?>
        <td><?php print $results['teamrf']; ?></td>
        <td><?php print $results['teamra']; ?></td>
<?php }
if ($show_gb) { ?>
        <td><?php print $gamesbehind; ?></td>
<?php } ?>
        <td><?php print $winningpct; ?></td>
<?php if ($show_points) { ?>
        <td><?php print $results['points']; ?></td>
<?php } ?>
    </tr>
<?php
        }
    }
?>
</table>
<?php } ?>

<a name="pastscores"></a><h2>Past Scores</h2>

<form name="teamsort" method="post" action="<?php print $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>#pastscores">
<p>
    Show only 
    <select name="teamtosort">
        <option value="all">All teams</option>
<?php
// Populate the list of teams
$queryteams = "SELECT sportsdb_teams.teamname, sportsdb_teams.teamid 
            FROM sportsdb_teams, sportsdb_divs 
            WHERE sportsdb_teams.teamdiv = sportsdb_divs.divid 
            AND sportsdb_divs.conference = $confid 
            ORDER BY teamname";
            
$resultteams=mysql_query($queryteams);
$numteams=mysql_num_rows($resultteams);

while ($teams = mysql_fetch_array($resultteams, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    print "\t" . '<option value="' . $teams['teamid'] . '"';
    if ($teams['teamid'] == $_POST['teamtosort']) { 
        print ' selected="selected"';
    }
    print '>' . $teams['teamname'] . "</option>\n";
}
?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</p>
</form>

<table class="scorestable">
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Home</th>
        <th>Away</th>
<?php if ($show_fields) { ?>
        <th>Field</th>
<?php } ?>
        <th>Score</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
<?php
$queryscores="SELECT sportsdb_wins.winid, sportsdb_wins.windate, sportsdb_wins.wintime, sportsdb_wins.rf, sportsdb_wins.ra, sportsdb_wins.winner,
    sportsdb_wins.loser, sportsdb_wins.wincomments, sportsdb_wins.field, sportsdb_wins.winortie, sportsdb_teams2.teamname AS winningteam,
    sportsdb_teams.teamname AS losingteam
    FROM sportsdb_wins
    LEFT JOIN sportsdb_teams ON sportsdb_wins.loser = sportsdb_teams.teamid
    LEFT JOIN sportsdb_teams AS sportsdb_teams2 ON sportsdb_wins.winner = sportsdb_teams2.teamid
    LEFT JOIN sportsdb_divs ON sportsdb_teams.teamdiv = sportsdb_divs.divid
    LEFT JOIN sportsdb_divs AS sportsdb_divs2 ON sportsdb_teams2.teamdiv = sportsdb_divs2.divid
    WHERE (sportsdb_divs.conference = $confid OR sportsdb_divs2.conference = $confid OR (sportsdb_wins.winconf = $confid AND (sportsdb_wins.loser = -1 OR sportsdb_wins.winner = -1))) AND sportsdb_wins.winortie != 3";

// Sort by team if specified
if (isset($_POST['teamtosort']) && $_POST['teamtosort'] != 'all') {
    $teamtosort = intval($_POST['teamtosort']);
    $queryscores .= " AND (sportsdb_wins.winner = $teamtosort OR sportsdb_wins.loser = $teamtosort)";
}

$queryscores .= ' ORDER BY wintime DESC';
$resultscores=mysql_query($queryscores);
$numscores=mysql_num_rows($resultscores);

while ($scores = mysql_fetch_array($resultscores, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    $windateheader=$scores['windate'];
    $windateformatted=date("F d, Y",$windateheader);
    $wintime=$scores['wintime'];
    $hour=date('g',$wintime);
    $minute=date('i',$wintime);
    $ampm=date('a',$wintime);
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php print $windateformatted; ?></td>
        <td><?php print $hour . ':' . $minute . $ampm; ?></td>
        <td><?php print $scores['winningteam']; ?></td>
        <td><?php print $scores['losingteam']; ?></td>
<?php if ($show_fields) { ?>
        <td><?php print $scores['field']; ?></td>
<?php } ?>
        <td><?php print $scores['rf'] . ' - ' . $scores['ra'];
    if ($scores['winortie'] == 2 || $scores['winortie'] == 5) {
        print ' (ff)';
    }
    print '</td>';
?>

        <td><?php print $scores['wincomments']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>

<a name="upcominggames"></a><h2>Upcoming Games</h2>
<form name="teamsort" method="post" action="<?php print $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>#upcominggames">
<p>Show only 
    <select name="teamtosort">
        <option value="all">All teams</option>
<?php
$queryteams = "SELECT sportsdb_teams.teamname, sportsdb_teams.teamid 
            FROM sportsdb_teams, sportsdb_divs 
            WHERE sportsdb_teams.teamdiv = sportsdb_divs.divid 
            AND sportsdb_divs.conference = $confid 
            ORDER BY teamname";
$resultteams=mysql_query($queryteams);
$numteams=mysql_num_rows($resultteams);

while ($teams = mysql_fetch_array($resultteams, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    print "\t" . '<option value="' . $teams['teamid'] . '"';
    if ($teams['teamid'] == $_POST['teamtosort']) {
        print ' selected';
    }
    print '>' . $teams['teamname'] . "</option>\n";
}
?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</p>
</form>

<table class="gamestable">
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Home</th>
        <th>Away</th>
<?php if ($show_fields) { ?>
        <th>Field</th>
<?php } ?>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
<?php
$queryscores = "SELECT sportsdb_wins.winid, sportsdb_wins.windate, sportsdb_wins.wintime, sportsdb_wins.winner, sportsdb_wins.loser, 
    sportsdb_wins.wincomments, sportsdb_wins.field, sportsdb_teams2.teamname AS winningteam, sportsdb_teams.teamname AS losingteam
    FROM sportsdb_wins
    LEFT JOIN sportsdb_teams ON sportsdb_wins.loser = sportsdb_teams.teamid
    LEFT JOIN sportsdb_teams AS sportsdb_teams2 ON sportsdb_wins.winner = sportsdb_teams2.teamid
    LEFT JOIN sportsdb_divs ON sportsdb_teams.teamdiv = sportsdb_divs.divid
    LEFT JOIN sportsdb_divs AS sportsdb_divs2 ON sportsdb_teams2.teamdiv = sportsdb_divs2.divid
    WHERE (sportsdb_divs.conference = $confid OR sportsdb_divs2.conference = $confid OR (sportsdb_wins.winconf = $confid AND (sportsdb_wins.loser = -1 OR sportsdb_wins.winner = -1))) AND sportsdb_wins.winortie = 3";

// Sort by team if specified
if (isset($_POST['teamtosort']) && $_POST['teamtosort'] != 'all') {
        $teamtosort = intval($_POST['teamtosort']);
        $queryscores .= " AND (sportsdb_wins.winner = $teamtosort OR sportsdb_wins.loser = $teamtosort)";
}

$queryscores .= ' ORDER BY wintime ASC';
$resultscores = mysql_query($queryscores);
$numscores = mysql_num_rows($resultscores);

while ($scores = mysql_fetch_array($resultscores, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    $windateheader=$scores['windate'];
    $windateformatted=date("F d, Y",$windateheader);
    $wintime=$scores['wintime'];
    $hour=date('g',$wintime);
    $minute=date('i',$wintime);
    $ampm=date('a',$wintime);
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php print $windateformatted; ?></td>
        <td><?php print $hour . ':' . $minute . $ampm; ?></td>
        <td><?php print $scores['winningteam']; ?></td>
        <td><?php print $scores['losingteam']; ?></td>
<?php if ($show_fields) { ?>
        <td><?php print $scores['field']; ?></td>
<?php } ?>
        <td><?php print $scores['wincomments'] ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
        }
?>
</table>
<?php
    }
}

// List the conference in a specified season

elseif (($show_season || isset($_GET['season'])) && !isset($_GET['seasons']) ) {
    if (!$show_season || isset($_GET['season']) ) {
        $show_season = intval($_GET['season']);
    }
    $query = 'SELECT seasonname FROM sportsdb_seasons WHERE seasonid = ' . $show_season . ' LIMIT 1';
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error in query ' . $query);
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        die ('There is no such season.');
    }
    $seasonname = mysql_result($result,0);
    $seasonname = htmlspecialchars($seasonname, ENT_QUOTES);
    print '<p><a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?seasons">Click here to view a list of seasons</a></p>' . "\n";
    print '<h3>' . $seasonname . ' season</h3>' . "\n";
?>
<p>Click on a conference name to view its standings</p>
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM sportsdb_conferences WHERE season = $show_season ORDER BY conforder";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error in query ' . $query);
    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
    while ($confs = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        print '<p><a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?conf={$confs['confid']}\">{$confs['confname']}</a></p>\n";
    }
}
else {
?>
<p>Click on a season name to view its conferences</p>
<?php
    // List the seasons
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM sportsdb_seasons ORDER BY seasonorder';
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error in query ' . $query);
    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
    while ($seasons = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $seasonname = htmlspecialchars($seasons['seasonname'], ENT_QUOTES);
        print '<p><a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?season={$seasons['seasonid']}\">$seasonname</a></p>\n";
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possibly you can set a class on the table based on whether it is group or head-to-head play, and add a class to each cell that is the column name. Then you can use CSS something like `.head-to-head .points { display: none; }`

Comment: Thank you Mr. Jerry 
I do not know If I can use Css with like Season Id or division id 
cause I have id for each seasons,divisions and Conferences
foe ex. i want to hide table from  division id 5 and at the i want the table visible at division 7
I think it will be less complicated to me 
my problem i do not know how can I generate Css  code and where I can put the code 
thank you again

Comment: If you direct your comment to @jerry instead of Mr. Jerry, they're more likely to see it.

Comment: OK, I don't think I understood your question very well, and I still don't, unfortunately. However, if you can write out exactly what the rules are for when the table shows and when it doesn't, the you can write code for that rule to set a `$show_table` variable, the same way you set `$show_fields`. I think your next step is to write out what that rule is in the language you are most comfortable with, then convert that to php.

Comment: ok, and sorry my English is not perfect,
I did not find any rule for this table 
just each games either in group or head to head it will appear 
I asked the script's  developer, he told me I can use css display none by using either division id or season id and that's the easiest way
the developer stopped support this script that's why I asked this question here